# How to use git for different development and production branch tracking?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm using Git and Gitflow for developing my own E-Commerce site.  I'd like to have slight differences between my develop and master branches, examples:

1. On the master (which will be my production site) I'd like to have my javascript and CSS minified to allow for faster page loads.  On the develop branch I'd like to use non minified scripts.
2. I'd like to track a folder called "install" on my develop branch, but I don't want that folder to be in my master branch.

I develop features on new branches and eventually merge those features into a release branch that is then merged into both my develop and master branches.  This process seems to overwrite the small differences I'd like to keep on my Master branch.  Is there a way to keep some changes on different branches from being overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

There's always `git stash`, which works somewhat like this:

```
$ git status
  # this actually contains changes; i.e., a non-clean index

$ git stash
  # this stores the local changes into a stash, which can be applied later

$ ... # whatever you need to do
$ git stash pop
```

Check out [`man git-stash`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html) if you need more information.